# converting range constraint into a domain constraint for parametric surface

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

The following is a parametric function for a sphere of radius 1:

$$f(\theta, \phi) = (\sin \phi \cos \theta,\ \ \  \sin \phi \sin \theta, \ \ \cos \phi) $$

How would you restrict the values of $\theta$ and $\phi$ to just get the portions of the sphere where:

$$ x \le 0,\ \ y \ge 0,\ \  z \le 0$$

---

So I separate the 3 equations:
$$
(x, y, z) = (\sin \phi \cos \theta,\ \ \  \sin \phi \sin \theta, \ \ \cos \phi) $$

equation 1:

$$ x = \sin \phi \cos \theta \le 0 $$

equation 2:

$$-y = -\sin \phi \sin \theta \le 0$$

equation 3:

$$z = \cos \phi \le 0$$

Then, I square equation 1 & square equation 2 and add them together:

$$
\sin^2 \phi \cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \phi \sin^2 \theta \le 0 
$$

$$
\sin^2 \phi\  ( \cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta) \le 0 
$$

$$
\sin^2 \phi\  \le 0 
$$

$$
\sin \phi\  \le 0 
$$

Now, I have two linearly independent equation left having $\phi$:

$$
\sin \phi\  \le 0 
$$

$$
\cos \phi\  \le 0 
$$

Taking the intersection of these two inequality equations, I get the range for $\phi$:

$$
\pi \le  \phi \le \frac{3\pi}{2}
$$

---

Now, I find the range for $\theta$:

Adding equation 1 & equation 2 together again, this time without squaring them, I get:

$$
\sin \phi \cos \theta - \sin \phi \sin \theta \le 0
$$

$$
\sin \phi ( \cos \theta - \sin \theta) \le 0
$$

$$
( \cos \theta - \sin \theta) \le 0
$$

dividing both sides by $\cos \theta$, i get:

$$
1 - \tan \theta \le 0
$$

$$
\tan \theta \ge 1
$$

from this I determine the range of $\theta$ is:

$$
\frac{\pi}{4} \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

**Now for my question:**

The book says the answer should be:

$$
\frac{\pi}{2} \le \theta \pi
$$

and

$$
\frac{\pi}{2} \le \phi \pi
$$

I'm wondering what I did wrong... and also not really understanding the books inequality of have a $\pi$ on both side of the inequality?

Comment: An important error is near the start where you state "I square equation 1 & square equation 2 and add them together". However, those $2$ "equations" are actually inequalities for values which are non-positive. Squaring them makes each of them non-negative. You can't just add them together and claim the result is non-positive. For example, $-1 \le 0$ and $-2 \le 0$, but $1 + 4 = 5 \le 0$ is definitely not true. I haven't checked the rest of your calculations, but this mistake will affect them significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tbh I think you're really shooting yourself in the foot going for this algebraically. This is really quite easy if you think about it in terms of spherical coordinates. [image: check this beautiful homemade diagram]
I think that $z=\cos \phi$ is the simplest thing to attack. $\phi$ is the angle that the vector $(x,y,z)$ makes with the $z$ axis, which means $ 0\le \phi \le \pi $ by default. Visually for $z \le 0$ we need  $ \phi \ge \frac{\pi}{2}$.
[image]
As for the $x$ and $y$ coordinates, we can use the usual ant moving around a circle analogy, since $(x,y)=\sin \phi (\cos \theta , \sin \theta)$ and $\sin \phi$ is a non-negative constant. For $x \le 0$ and $ y \ge 0$ we want to go in the second quadrant. thus $\pi \ge \theta \ge \frac{\pi}{2}$

I think the $\pi$s in the books answers are just typos. Also a with inequalities you need to be really careful when multiplying by constants to make sure that that constant is not negative. Not doing this led to a lot of errors in your work.